# Connect to DB using click command python

Tags: python, pycharm, python-click

How to connect to a database using python-click?
For example: 
`YourPythonScript.py -e 'Excel file' -d 'Database Name'`

```
@click.command()                                                                                  
@click.option('--generate', '-g', help='Change TEXT to generate excel file into SQL insert')      
@click.option('--database', '-d', help='Change TEXT to connect in the database')                  
    def main(generate, database):                                                                     
        try:                                                                                          
            # Validate generate file can not be None                                                  
            if generate is None:                                                                      
                raise TypeError                                                                       
            # Check if outputted is not None                                                          
            if database is not None:                                                                  
                try:                                                                                  
                    # Connect to DB                                                                   
                    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'                                      
                                          'Server=Comp-MMD\EXPRESS;'                           
                                          'Database=DBSample;'                                        
                                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read the formatting help in order to properly format source code samples. You'll also want to update this question to include an actual question: are you getting an error? Unexpected behavior? Please describe the problem with which you would like some assistance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.